# Why are ListViewItems within ContentControl only selectable on first few pixels?

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate, listviewitem

I want to request different types of properties from the user of my WPF application. Therefore I have a `ListView` thats `ItemsSource` binds to an `ObservableCollection<PropertiesBase>`. Each property derives from `PropertiesBase`. As an expert user should be able to edit these properties, the `DataTemplate` is selected depending on the `EditMode` Property and the type of the property.

Data display and everything else works fine, **except that I am not able to select a ListViewItem.** Only when I click a textbox inside a `ListViewItem` or the first few pixels of the item I am able to select an item.

[The selection only works on the white part of the item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb0cW.png)

I have tried to play around with Focusable but it does not led me to success. I also copied my xaml of the ListViewItem directly into the Listview (without datatemplate). That worked as expected.

ListView XAML:

```xaml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyList}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type properties:PasswordProperty}">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Background="Red">
                      <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PasswordPropertyListViewItem}" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditMode, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditPasswordPropertyListViewItem}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Example ListViewItem XAML that is referenced by DataTemplate:

```xml
<ListViewItem x:Class="PasswordPropertyListViewItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"  BorderBrush="DarkGray">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label Margin="8" Content="{Binding PropertyName}"></Label>
```

I expect that it does not matter where I click onto the ListViewItem but the item is selected in any case (Especially the red part of the image above).

Comment: Your component structure is unclear. Do you really have a ContentTemplate with a derived ListViewItem for a ContentControl in a DataTemplate for items in a ListView? This DataTemplate would be used as ContentTemplate of the ListViewItems that are automatically generated by the ListView. The result would be two nested ListViewItems per item.

Comment: Try setting IsHitTestVisible property of the ContentControl inside the template to _false_ and see whether it improves things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) provided a solution in his [comment above.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497351/why-are-listviewitems-within-contentcontrol-only-selectable-on-first-few-pixels/56497857#comment99583904_56497351) 
I indeed nested two `ListViewItems`.

The solution is to change the type of my templated control to `ContentControl`.

```xaml
<ContentControl x:Class="PasswordPropertyListViewItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"  BorderBrush="DarkGray">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label Margin="8" Content="{Binding PropertyName}"></Label>
```

Thanks Clemens!